# textutil converts font to Helvetica-Light instead of Helvetica

Tags: bash

In bash on mac os 10.6.8, I'm using textutil to convert a .txt file to .rtf:

```
textutil -convert rtf -font Helvetica file.txt
```

Yet to my frustration, it always converts the font to Helvetica-Light, instead of just Helvetica. How can I make sure it chooses just the regular Helvetica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `/Library/Fonts` folder, the font name shown was **HelveticaCY**.

Modify the command to be:

```
textutil -convert rtf -font "HelveticaCY" file.txt
```